# Showing x^m is differentiable

Tags: analysis, functions, derivatives

[image]

f(x)=x^m and m is a natural number. 
And so, f is differentiable. This is because take g(x)=x, which is differentiable, and multiply it m times, and so by the product rule of differentiation, it is differentiable. 
However, I do not understand how (x^m - c^m)/(x-c) becomes mc^(m-1).

Comment: This is precisely what the image explains !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because\begin{align}(x^{m-1}+cx^{m-2}+\cdots+c^{m-1})(x-c)&=x^m-cx^{m-1}+cx^{m-1}-cx^{m-2}+\cdots+xc^{m-1}-c^m\\&=x^m-c^m\end{align}and because\begin{align}\lim_{x\to c}x^{m-1}+cx^{m-2}+\cdots+c^{m-1}&=c^{m-1}+c\times c^{m-2}+\cdots+c^{m-1}\\&=\overbrace{c^{m-1}+c^{m-1}+\cdots+c^{m-1}}^{m\text{ times}}\\&=mc^{m-1}.\end{align}

Comment: But how is (x^m - c^m)/(x-c) = x^m-1 + cx^m-2 + ... + c^m-1?

Comment: Multiply both sides of that equality by $x-c$ and you will get $x^m-c^m$ twice.

Comment: I get that lim as x tends to c of (x^m-1 + cx^m-2 + ... + c^m-1) is: c^m-1 + c^m-1 + ... + c^m-1 (m times), and thus mc^m-1. But im confused about the first equality in the picture I posted.

Comment: Did you read my previous comment?

Comment: Yes I did, I had posted it and you had commented right after.

Comment: Thank you very much though

Comment: I have expanded my answer. Is everything clear now?

Comment: Perfectly clear. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

A much better method is mathematical induction. The statement to be proved is "For all positive integers m, the derivative of $x^m$ is $mx^{m-1}."$ The statement has already been proved for the case $m=1.$ Assume the statement is true for $m=\nu.$ For $m=\nu+1$, we have
$$f(x)=x^{\nu+1}$$ $$=xx^{\nu}.$$ By the product rule,
$$f'(x)=1 \times x^{\nu}+x \times \nu x^{\nu -1}$$
$$=(\nu+1)x^{\nu}, Q.E.D.$$